# Handsontable - Change row height - jumpy scroll

Tags: scroll, handsontable, row-height

I try to change the row height of the table with css

http://jsfiddle.net/aep5bo3r/1/

I added this to change the row height.

```
#basic_example td
{
     height: 15px!important;
    line-height: 15px!important;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

The rows height is smaller, but now the scroll is .. jumpy?

With the default row height the cells are added nicely when scrolling, but if the rows are smaller, it won't add new rows until you scrolled past a certain portion.

I guess the javascript part doesn't like the new change.

If you can help me solve this, having smaller row height with an working scroll, it would be nice.

Thanks;

Comment: this might a bug so please post it on the github page of issues for handsontable. the problem is with the virtual rendering: the standard behavior is to only render what the user can see. My guess is that the virtual renderer calculates what the user can see by using a value of the row height which, when lowered, isn't being reflected. Therefore, you need to scroll enough so that the renderer reaches the number of rows with the original height

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well so your problem will be solved if we add `renderAllRows: true` to your settings option when creating Handsontable object.

```
var hot = new Handsontable($('#tableContainerId')[0], {
         ...
         renderAllRows: true,
         ...
});
```

Comment: This works but still leaving the space at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but incase someone is needed.

You need to change the CSS to:

```css
.handsontable td, .handsontable th, .handsontableInput {
    height: 15px !important;
    line-height: 15px !important;
}
```

... and also add this option to the table:

```js
{
...
rowHeights: 15,
}
```